# Why is 'chose' not preceded by a determinative in this sentence

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

This is from Proust

> Le docteur, cependant, poussait Mme Verdurin à laisser jouer le pianiste, non pas qu’il crût feints les troubles que la musique lui donnait – il y reconnaissait certains états neurasthéniques – mais par cette habitude qu’ont beaucoup de médecins de faire fléchir immédiatement la sévérité de leurs prescriptions dès qu’est en jeu,
> **chose** qui leur semble beaucoup plus importante, quelque réunion mondaine dont ils font partie et dont la personne à qui ils conseillent d’oublier pour une fois sa dyspepsie, ou sa grippe, est un des facteurs essentiels.

I've checked that there are no typos in the above sentence [here](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Proust_-_Du_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_chez_Swann.djvu/275).  In the above sentence 'chose' is not precded by a determinative.  Why?  Defining a determinative is a bit hard but roughly any of the words such as de, des, le, les, autre, ces, cette, quelque and a few others are determinatives.  I checked about 20 examples of 'chose' in Proust and all except one was preceded by a determinative.

> L’influence anesthésiante de l’habitude ayant cessé, je me mettais à penser, à sentir, choses si tristes

I also found another analogous case, here 'fiction' is not preceded by a determinative:

> Mme Verdurin s’immobilisa, prit une expression inerte comme si elle était devenue une statue, fiction/ qui lui permit d’être censée ne pas avoir entendu ce mot insupportable de poseur qui avait l’air d’impliquer qu’on pouvait « poser » avec eux, donc qu’on était « plus qu’eux ».

Comment: In addition to the appositions mentioned in the answers, French also has a few cases of *syntagme nominal à article nul/zéro* - "null-article noun phrases". See *chose facile* in I. B. 1. c) here https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans tous les cas, il s'agit d'appositions descriptives, c'est à dire de descriptions détachées destinées à enrichir ce qui est écrit mais que l'on pourrait retirer de la phrase sans que sa grammaire ou son sens en soit affectés. Ces appositions pourraient tout aussi bien être mises entre parenthèses, moins ici car elle est antéposée :

> [...]mais par cette habitude qu’ont beaucoup de médecins de faire fléchir immédiatement la sévérité de leurs prescriptions dès qu’est en jeu (chose qui leur semble beaucoup plus importante) quelque réunion mondaine dont ils font partie[...]

Les appositions descriptives sont souvent construites sans article :

> Souvent, pour s’amuser, les hommes d’équipage
> Prennent des albatros, **vastes oiseaux des mers**,
> Qui suivent, indolents compagnons de voyage,

*L'Albatros*, Charles Baudelaire

---

In all cases, these are descriptive appositions, i.e. detached descriptions intended to enrich what is written but which could be removed from the sentence without affecting its grammar or meaning. These appositions could just as easily be put in parentheses, less so here because it is anteposed:

> *[...]mais par cette habitude qu’ont beaucoup de médecins de faire fléchir immédiatement la sévérité de leurs prescriptions dès qu’est en jeu (chose qui leur semble beaucoup plus importante) quelque réunion mondaine dont ils font partie[...]*

Descriptive appositions are often built without an article:

> *Souvent, pour s’amuser, les hommes d’équipage
>
> Prennent des albatros, **vastes oiseaux des mers**,
>
> Qui suivent, indolents compagnons de voyage,*

*L'Albatros*, Charles Baudelaire

Comment: Thanks, that makes everything clear.   I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

In appositive function it is usual not to use a determinative; it should be "un", "une" or "des" but in this usage the indefinite article is not referential. The article can be used, and there is even the possibility, often, to turn the noun phrase into an independent clause by adding "c'est", "c'était", and doing that changes nothing to the meaning.

An apposition is a juxtaposition of a noun phrase that describes most often what precedes or less often what follows or says something about it; it is set between commas.

- Elle n'avait rien dans son sac, chose que le voleur ne savait pas.
  *Elle n'avait rien dans son sac, une chose que le voleur ne savait pas.*
  *Elle n'avait rien dans son sac, c'était une chose que le voleur ne savait pas.*
- Ils répétaient ces mensonges, mensonges que certains finissaient par croire.
  *Ils répétaient ces mensonges, des mensonges que certains finissaient par croire.*
  *Ils répétaient ces mensonges, c'était des mensonges que certains finissaient par croire.*

Comment: A minor detail: in the first example of the question, the apposition describes what follows, not what precedes.

Comment: @jlliagre I really don't get it; what's in apposition is "chose que…" and it says that the fact that there is nothing in the bag is something that the robber doesn't know; it says something about "there is nothing in the bag"; that is before, not after. What can you have in mind?

Comment: Read my comment closer.

Comment: @jlliagre I get it now; in fact it is true that it can refer to something after quite often.

Comment: A million thanks, as always.